How to pass class variables into a websocket resource method with Flask?
I'm trying to access a class variable within my websocket resource method, so that I can store the websocket instance into a class variable and later send a websocket message from another method.
app = Flask(__name__) 
sock = Sock(app)

    @sock.route('/connect')
    def connect(ws):
        ws.send('connected')

        while True: 
            data = ws.receive() 

I want to be able to call self.ws = ws from inside the method.
I'm currently using flask_sock.
It doesnt work to pass "self" into  the method. I know that with flask_restful library, you can pass data into a resource method with the resource_class_kwargs argument to the add_resource method.
Is there an equivalent argument for regular flask/websocket endpoints?
Or, can you define a websocket route with flask_restful? That way I can use flask_restful and pass in the data that way.
I also tried using session but can't because the method I want to access the websocket instance in later is a regular method/a callback, and not an endpoint, and session can only be accessed from endpoints.
I'm open to any way in which I can save the websocket instance and later access it from a separate class method. Thank you!
